# Setup Interactive Brokers C++ API as Console application

Tags: c#, c++

Is there a way that I could setup the C++ api not as a Windows Form application, but as a console application. An example of how this might work:

```
if(AAPL.price == 250)
{
    AAPL.buy(500);
}
```

I would run it as a console application and have it refresh every couple seconds so that I don't have to debug it every 2 seconds.

I would not mind if you suggest something that exists in a different programming language, I would prefer C++ or C#, but anything else would be helpful. Thanks :D !

Comment: You'll need to give us more context than that. With just the code snippet you have there, there's not a lot that anyone can do to help you (and the question's vagueness doesn't help, either).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider  https://github.com/JanBoonen/TwsApiCpp  and  https://github.com/rudimeier/twsapi as starting points.

Answer (score 0):

Kangaroo Software offers a C++ console application and source code to access the Interactive Brokers API. You can setup conditions using XML or edit the code and create your own logic.

http://www.kangaroosoftware.com/StockBot.aspx

Comment: Kangaroo Software is a bit pricy, is their anything else that is cheaper?